# Calculating Time Duration

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column-formula, time

Working within SP, I have two columns Tech Checkin and Tech Checkout with a third column titled Visit Duration.

The tech checkin and check out columns will contain a time only and are set as single line of text (I do not want a date populated in that column).  The Visit Duration column should take the checkin and checkout times and create a sum equal to duration.

For example, tech check in is 12:00 PM and tech checkout is 1:27 PM.  I want the Visit Duration column to read 1:27.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint doesn't have parsing functions to automatically convert text to times. I'd recommend using a datetime field anyway, as that prevents data entry issues as well as makes the time calculation much simpler. If you must allow users to enter text, a developer could add an event handler or implement an Azure function to parse the string and perform the calculation.

Or, for brittle solution that will break frequently:

```
=(TIME(left([txtTime],2),mid([txtTime],4,2),"00")-TIME(left([txtTime2],2),mid([txtTime2],4,2),"00"))*1440
```

The above will require times to be entered with leading zeroes, as:

```
06:00 am
```

And that's what a meant by brittle, if someone enters the time inconsistently, the function will throw an error. You'll also need to add an if statement to check for am/pm to conditionally add 12 hours to the first argument.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following forumla:

```
INT(([Tech Checkout]-[Tech Checkin])*24)&":"&MOD(INT(([Tech Checkout]-[Tech Checkin])*1440),60)
```

[image]

Result: `Tech Checkin` and `Tech Checkout` are single line of text fields

[image]

[Calculated Field Formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-common-formulas-in-sharepoint-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)

[Calculated Field Formulas with demos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))

*Note: If the answer helps you, don't forget to accept it as the best answer. It will help others find the answer/solution quickly*